# Specifying Area to search for Views in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app which currently uses one Area (in addition to the normal location). Normally everything is working fine with my routing, but I now have a need for code in the 'root' location to find a partial view which is inside the area.

The relevant parts of my solution's files are:

```
/Areas
/Areas/Admin
/Areas/Admin/Views
/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_adminPartialView.cshtml
/Views
/Views/Shared/_rootPartialView.cshtml
```

And my failing code is:

```
var viewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
var cContext = new ControllerContext(context, new RouteData(), new EmptyController());

// this works:
var rootView = viewEngine.FindPartialView(cContext, "_rootPartialView", false);
if (rootView == null) { throw new Exception("Root view not found"); }

// this throws my error:
var adminView = viewEngine.FindPartialView(cContext, "_adminPartialView", false);
if (adminView == null) { throw new Exception("Admin view not found"); }
```

(`context` above is coming indirectly from HttpContext.Current)

... which makes sense, without an Area specified the Admin area shouldn't be searched... But when I change my `viewEngine` above to  `= new AdminRazorViewEngine();`, which is defined as:

```
public class AdminRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine {
    public AdminRazorViewEngine() {
        var viewLocations = new [] {
            "~/Areas/Admin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        base.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations.Concat(base.ViewLocationFormats).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I still get the same results.

If I copy `_adminPartialView.cshtml` to `/Views/Shared/` then both views are found correctly, using either view engine.

I've also tried creating an actual RouteData object, specifying the Area on it, and using that when constructing my ControllerContext:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeDate.Values.Add("area", "Admin");
// ...
var cContext = new ControllerContext(context, routeData, new EmptyController());
```

With no change in behavior.

How can I explicitly specify an area for the view engine to search in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `AreaViewLocationFormats` instead of `ViewLocationFormats`

Here is the code from ILSpy for the `RazorViewEngine`

```
    public RazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator) : base(viewPageActivator)
    {
        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        base.FileExtensions = new string[]
        {
            "cshtml",
            "vbhtml"
        };
    }
```

Comment: D'oh. I was looking for a Partial View, but not adding to PartialViewLocationFormats